# adding new random number after a link on every press

Tags: javascript, html, random, hyperlink, href

the goal of my code is to generate a new link each time "generate" is pressed, so that i can find new songs for geometry dash without having to spam numbers.

i have tried the string below but every time the button were to be clicked, it would append a new set of numbers on the end. i wish for the program to not require a refresh

```
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(link =>
     link.setAttribute("href", link.getAttribute("href") + Math.floor(Math.random() * 111392.8) + 1)
```

this is my current attempt. i have gotten the goal of a new number on every button press with a refresh but the prefix of "https://www.newgrounds.com/audio/listen/" won't append to the start.

```js
window.onclick = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(link =>
    link.setAttribute("href", Math.floor(Math.random() * 111392.8) + 1)
  );
};
```

```html
<title>
  Newgrounds Song Generator
</title>

<body>

  <h1>Click the button to visit a random song!</h1>

  <a href="https://www.newgrounds.com/audio/listen/" target="_blank">
    <button>Generate</button>
  </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have a button in a link!

The code can be much simpler with a form

```js
const url = "https://www.newgrounds.com/audio/listen/";
document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener("submit", function() {
  const link = url + Math.floor(Math.random() * 111392.8) + 1;
  console.log(link)
  this.action = link; // SO does not allow a target="_blank" in a snippet
})
```

```html
<title>
  Newgrounds Song Generator
</title>
<h1>Click the button to visit a random song!</h1>
<form id="generate" target="_blank">
  <button type="submit">Generate</button>
</form>
```

Or a link styled as a button

```js
const url = "https://www.newgrounds.com/audio/listen/";
document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener("click", function() {
  const link = url + Math.floor(Math.random() * 111392.8) + 1;
  console.log(link)
  this.href = link; // SO does not allow a target="_blank" in a snippet
})
```

```css
.button {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<title>
  Newgrounds Song Generator
</title>
<h1>Click the button to visit a random song!</h1>
<a class="button" id="generate" target="_blank" href="">Generate</a>
```

Comment: @WaamyCookie Is this still the case? If not, please delete the comment since it confuses those who come after

Answer (score -2):

You have some problems with it:

- You shouldn't use **script** tag inside the **head** tag.
- You shouldn't use **button** tag inside an **anchor** tag.
- You shouldn't use **window.onclick** because it will activate the function no matter where you click.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS1.css">
</head>

<title>
  Newgrounds Song Generator
</title>

<body>

  <h1>Click the button to visit a random song!</h1>


  <button id="listen">
Generate
</button>


</body>

<script>
  const baseUrl = "https://www.newgrounds.com/audio/listen/";
  document.getElementById("listen").onclick = () => {
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = baseUrl + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 111392.8) + 1);
    a.target = '_blank';
    a.click();
  };
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Script is fine in the head. Also it is recommended to use eventlisteners instead of onevent